# Can the network admin see my chat message?

Tags: chat

When I use yahoo web messenger or google hangout in my internet browswer, I can see that the communication happens using HTTPS protocol, which means that the data is encrypted using SSL certificate. Does it mean that the chat message that I sent cannot be interpreted and seen by network Admin?

Comment: A normal network admin can't see that messages but a cleverer one can see this using some tricks.

Comment: What is the trick that you think a clever person can use to see my message?. I thought one needs to hack the SSL to break the encryption to see the message, so I am wondering what trick you are referring to

Comment: check out this link there are number of tools that can be used by network admin. http://www.gfi.com/blog/the-top-20-free-network-monitoring-and-analysis-tools-for-sys-admins/

Comment: @WaQaRAli you seem to have something more specific in mind, but that link lists a bunch of general-purpose scanning tools. Can you elaborate more on what you envision would undermine HTTPS in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, no he can't. Https creates a tunnel between your computer and Google Hangouts.

What he can usually see is the package header, showing clearly that this message is intended to go to Google Hangouts. He doesn't see its contents.

Yet, it's not a big problem for an admin to install some sort of keylogger on your system. Installing stuff on your computer is his job. So, when you worry that this admin is targeting you specifically, well that's possible. If you're worried about general snooping, no he won't see your chats' contents.

Comment: Note that there's a significant difference between a _system_ admin and a _network_ admin.

Comment: @Joost Good point

Comment: Ok. I got what I wanted. So the network admin cannot see the content of the chat message. Cool.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS just guarantees that only the certificate-owner can read your messages. As the certificate belongs to the website, not your chat partner, then yes, anyone server-side can see your message in plaintext.

If someone is snooping/tampering with the network traffic they can't read the plaintext without you noticing; e.g. replacing the website certificate with one that pretends to be from that server, but which won't be signed by a trusted authority.